# Custom Web Parts on SharePoint Mobile App

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app

When migrating an existing SP 2013 On-Prem to SP Online using SPMT or ShareGate and given there are a number of custom Wb Parts and other customizations done mostly with SharePoint designer.

I know that maybe we will need to recreate some web parts as Add-Ins or Hosted Apps.
But my question for this post is about the SharePoint Mobile App.

Should we allocate dev and QA time for validating and fixing issues in the Mobile Apps for iOS and Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no need for a mobile devs since Microsoft has provided as a [SharePoint App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.sharepoint&hl=en)

QA I would say yes, and Web developers that knows Microsoft platforms for Modern SharePoint ([SPFX](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part), React, TypeScript, [SPPnp](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/getting-started/), Javascript). SharePoint online (I could say O365 as a whole) has followed [Fabric UI](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/styles) design, if it works in Web, it will and should also work in SharePoint app.

OOTB functionalities should work well while custom webparts will work depends on the compatibility of the services that modern sharepoint supports, anyhow leave that issues to the web devs :) .

Hope the concept contributes, Good Day!

Comment: I liked this part: "if it works in Web, it will and should also work in SharePoint app". So it means that for mobile, there shouldn’t be extra dev work assuming all web issues were sorted.

Comment: For out of the box SharePoint, Yes, the custom ones like webparts, add ins, etc will still depends on the compatibility of the services that modern sharepoint supports. If functionalities only scopes inside SharePoint and have followed that standard coding structures provided by MS and Pnp, there shouldn't be a problem (but do consider sharepoint permission structure)  :)

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-classic-and-modern-experiences-5725c103-505d-4a6e-9350-300d3ec7d73f), modern pages (and in fact all modern features) are designed to be responsive and look great on mobile devices.

So SharePoint add-in in modern page will work well in mobile app.

More information:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-mobile-app-for-ios-339402ce-16bb-4c97-9475-0c5375ccef7a

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-mobile-app-for-android-d875654b-fb0a-4dbe-a17a-a676cf936284

Comment: Thanks! So it is correct to say that in a SP2013 to Online migration project, every classic web part needs to be refactored to become a modern web part if you want to assure that the mobile app will be working well, right? In that case makes sense to add budget specifically for mobile compatibility, agree?